# making a gallery with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using php to populate a thumbnail gallery. When I click on the thumb I run a javascript function in which I want to put the photo that I clicked on in a div called viewer. I don't know how to say that in my function.

here's what I have so far

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>img.thumb{height:100px; display:inline-block;} .thumb{position:relative; display:inline-block;}</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showfull(){
    console.log("hello");
    document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = "<? echo '<img onclick="showfull();" id="'.$thispic.'" class="thumb" src = "../images/'.$pic.'"/><br/><h1 id="'.$thistitle.'" class="title">'.$maruja['pictitle'].'</h1><br/><h2 id="'.$thisdescript.'" class="description">'.$maruja['picdesc'].'</h2>'; ?>";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<?
//show categories in dropdown
$sql = $dbh->prepare("select * from 3304gallcats");
$sql->execute();
while ($carolyn  = $sql->fetch()){
     echo '<a href = "index.php?catid='.$carolyn['catid'].'">'.$carolyn['catname'].'</a><br/>';
}

$catid = $_GET['catid'];
$picsql = $dbh->prepare("select * from 3304gallpix where catid = '$catid'");
$picsql->execute();
while ($maruja  = $picsql->fetch()){
     $pic = $maruja['id'].'.jpg' ;
     $thispic = 'num'.$maruja['id'].'pic';
     $thistitle = 'num'.$maruja['id'].'title';
     $thisdescript = 'num'.$maruja['id'].'descript';
     echo '<img onclick="showfull();" id="'.$thispic.'" class="thumb" src = "../images/'.$pic.'"/><br/><h1 id="'.$thistitle.'" class="title">'.$maruja['pictitle'].'</h1><br/><h2 id="'.$thisdescript.'" class="description">'.$maruja['picdesc'].'</h2>';
     //echo '<img src = "./thumbnail.php?pic=../images/'.$pic.'&ht=100&wd=100"/><br/>'.$maruja['pictitle'].'<br/>'.$maruja['picdesc'];
}


?>
<div id="viewer"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: I guess what I should be asking is what does my .innerHTML need to be equal to, to display the pic that I click on

Answer (score 0):

it's not very clear to me for what purpose the showfull() function should be used for..
my suggest is to use the javascript (jquery) code to display the final image. Let's say 
we have a thumbnails div and a full-image div: (put this in the "head" section)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showfull(){ 
     $("#thumbnails img").on("click", function() {
        var clicked_img = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#full_image img").attr("src", clicked_img);
     });
  // don't rely on this javascript code as you can find 
  // a lot of plugins for thumbnails on the internet that does this even better
  }
</script>
```

put the following in the "body" section (customize the image attributes as you need ..)

```
<div id="thumbnails"></div>
<div id="full_image"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
```

....  use a php variable to build a string that will be displayed as html in the thumbnails div :

```
....
$html = '';
while($maruja = $picsql->fetch()) {
   // .... stuff ..
   $html .= '<img onclick="showfull();" src="your-source" etc........ />';
}
```

finally display that variable in the viewer div

```
<div id="thumbnails"><?php echo $html; ?></div>
```

your html will look like this:

```
<div id="thumbnails">
   <img onclick="showfull();" src="your-source" etc........ />
   <img onclick="showfull();" src="your-source" etc........ />
   <img onclick="showfull();" src="your-source" etc........ />
   ....
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the thumbnails the showfull() function will be called.
That's all. If you want to use your code you must escape the quotes to avoid js errors :

```
document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = "<img onclick=\"showfull();\" id=\"<?php echo $thispic; ?>\" class=\"thumb\" src=\"<?php echo '../images/' . $pic; ?>\" />";
```

I hope that this helps ...